# Do any OR Mappers provide Asynchronous Methods?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, data-access-layer, or-mapper

Do any .Net O/R (object/Relational) Mappers provide Asynchronous methods out of the box?

I don't want to have to write the boiler plate for the asynchronous method if possible

I have rolled my own DAL with Asynchronous methods using the CCR framework.
The CCR basically demands that I don't block any of it's threads waiting for IO responses.

The good part about my solution so far is that it is down to the bare minimum.  But as this project grows in terms of scale and functionality, I am facing the mildly daunting task of maintaining raw SQL queries and boiler plate code.

BUT on the other hand if the O/R mapper Asynchronous methods are really just a messy hack that adds oddles of complexity I am not better off.

Please don't focus on alternatives to Asynchronous programming.

Comment: This sounds like a good case of premature optimization... in all the "high scalability" stuff I've ever seen, 2 things seem to be key - denormalize your DB, and cache cache cache... nothing about async IO

Comment: It is a simple question, are there any OR Mappers which provide Asynchronous Methods? Yes or No?

I think that it is fair to say that in my particular project I am in the better position to determine if this is over kill.

Comment: In defence of @Orion Edwards, you said "all I/O requests", which does seem like overkill.  If someone calls your service and you respond Ok, then you system crashes you will lose the queued I/O.  Is this ok for your solution?

Comment: At this stage of the game I have written the backend DAL asynchronously via the SqlCommand methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not sure if any of them do it out of the box, you could use [.NetTiers](http://nettiers.com/), which is template based. You could just add the async parts to the template. That would at least eliminate you having to maintain the boilerplate code and bare SQL queries. This [blog](http://williablog.net/williablog/post/2008/12/01/Add-Asynchronous-Data-Methods-to-the-Enterprise-Library.aspx) shows how to add async calls to the MS Enterprise library (which .NetTiers can use if you choose).

As of mid-December 2008, LLBLGen Pro does not natively support async calls. Currently [Genome](http://www.genom-e.com/) doesn't either. It doesn't appear that [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm.aspx) does either. Pretty much just searched their documentation and looked for either async or methods that start with begin because that's the pattern.

I let the other answers speak as to if it's a good idea or not...

Comment: thanks.  Programmers are great with advice.  sometimes we just need an answer

Comment: It's not an answer, as it won't help you. But alas, I'm not the one with the question. LLBLGen Pro doesn't support async calls because it creates an awkward way of doing data-access and at the same time the developer can do it him/herself by creating a worker thread. The problem remains: callbacks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for SQLAlchemy (one of the best ORMs), there is sAsync:

http://foss.eepatents.com/sAsync

and NADBAPI:

http://developer.berlios.de/projects/nadbapi/

Answer (score 2):

I think you got it wrong. My understanding is that asynchronous execution in your case should be handled at architecture level instead of ORM level i.e. message queue driven architecture. What I see is that your webserive will only place a message in the queue and there is some kind of background agent does the asynchronous processing off the queue.

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment and Stackoverflow is alerting me inserting another "answer" I will leave my comment here.

Lee B: SQLAlchemy? How do you use it with .NET???

Answer (score 1):

Fetching data in an asynchronous way can be accomplished in various ways. To outsource it to an o/r mapper gives challenges which you probably don't want to deal with as it doesn't really make your code less complex. The main problem is that you have to have a mechanism which is notified when the fetch is completed by the o/r mapper, so the caller is notified that data is ready.

This isn't less complex than creating a thread yourself and call the o/r mapper's fetch logic from that thread.

As you state that you want to create a webservice which should be responsive, you've to realize that the caller is outside the webservice and waits for data. I.o.w.: if the caller uses the webservice for fetching data, it's already asynchronous, as other clients will still be able to call the webservice as well: the original caller's request is handled on a different thread, logic to fetch the data is ran inside that thread, and the data is then returned to the caller.

Using asynchronous methods is of no use here, as the caller would otherwise have to be notified when the data is ready, which requires a push from the webservice to the client, which requires the client to stay connected to the webservice as long as the fetch takes anyway.

Asynchronous db interaction isn't magic things you can throw at something so it gets more responsive. Asynchronous db interaction could make the caller do other things in the mean time. However if that's already not necessary, you don't need asynchronous db interaction to begin with, which will make your code a lot less complex.

Comment: In summary: you don't need async methods in your webservice as it's already using a system where a request isn't blocking other requests.

Comment: A thread blocked is one less thread available for other requests.  Get enough threads blocked waiting on IO and your requests queue, the queue fills up and your now returning 'Service Unavailable' messages

Comment: Yes requests happen in parallel to each other.  But they share the same system resources.  So the more efficently I can use the thread pool the more requests the system can handle

Comment: Harry, you don't get my point about async methods need to call back to the caller to get their results marshalled back: how are you going to do that in a webservice? I.o.w.: what you want isn't possible.

Comment: If you're building a WCF duplex service, you _shouldn't_ block while processing requests. That is why async methods would be useful.

Comment: One more note: You can do async pages with ASP.Net. That's another place where async db access would be extremely useful. You're wrong Frans Bouma.

Answer (score 0):

[Nhibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) seems to be relatively easier to implement Async than LinqToSQL. See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/AsyncDataloading.aspx?display=PrintAll)

Personally what I would do though is use what I am comfortable with (as I haven't used NHibernate I would worry about the learning curve and potential issues so I would rather use something like LINQtoSQL or bespoke data access layer) and wrap it in it's own web service of [WCF LOB Adapter](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=56278fde-b708-469c-987e-ded9c6c5e580&displaylang=en).

If you really didn't want to code  that yourself you could just use [ADO.NET Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx) which does basically that for the Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are missing some indexes.

Or you need to shift database design to OLAP model.

If that is not the case.

1. Get more ram.
2. Get more CPU.
3. Partition your tables.
4. Build a wrapper infront of the DB that can handle async requests. It will look like a queue.

Comment: Missing indexes? not sure how you came to that diagnosis.
Would love to convince the boss to throw hardware at the problem.